# makefile one compile call for multiple sources with headers excluded

Tags: makefile

For verilog compilations, it is advantageous to compile many verilog files at once - and they get compiled into a database (no .o files). I have found that I can create a rule like:

```
SOURCES := src1.v src2.v src3.v
verilog.timestamp: $(SOURCES) hdr.vh
    xmvlog $(if $(filter-out $(SOURCES),$(?)),$(SOURCES),$(filter $(?),$(SOURCES)))
```

This allows for only the outdated files to be recompiled (or all of them when the header is out of date). It feels pretty ugly - is there a nicer way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Beta, the `$?` automatic variable can be handy in this case because it expands as the list of all prerequisites that are newer than the target (except order-only prerequisites). But we still need to address your other problem: your Verilog compiler does not produce one single binary file per compiled Verilog source. Moreover, you want to recompile a Verilog source file `foo.v` if `foo.v` or the `hdr.vh` header file has been modified since the last time `foo.v` was compiled. There is a pure make way which consists in using empty files as markers, one per Verilog source file plus one for the whole project:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.v)
TAGS    := $(patsubst %.v,.%.tag,$(SOURCES))

all: verilog.timestamp

.PHONY: all

$(TAGS): .%.tag: %.v hdr.vh
    touch $@

verilog.timestamp: $(TAGS)
    xmvlog $(patsubst .%.tag,%.v,$?)
    touch $@

clean::
    rm -f $(TAGS) verilog.timestamp
```

Explanations: in order to build `all` (the default and phony goal), make will try to build `verilog.timestamp`. It will thus look to see if any of the `$(TAGS)` is out of date, that is, older than the corresponding Verilog source file or the `hdr.vh` header file. If none, it will stop. Else, it will:

1. Build the outdated tag files, only them, potentially in parallel (this Makefile is parallel safe) by just touching them.
2. Build `verilog.timestamp`. When expanding the recipe, just before passing it to the shell, make will substitute `$(patsubst .%.tag,%.v,$?)` by all Verilog source files corresponding to tag files that were just rebuilt and are thus newer than `verilog.timestamp`. Finally, it will touch `verilog.timestamp`.

Demonstration:

```
$ make clean
rm -f .src3.tag .src2.tag .src1.tag verilog.timestamp

$ make -j8
touch .src3.tag
touch .src2.tag
touch .src1.tag
xmvlog src3.v src2.v src1.v
touch verilog.timestamp

$ make -j8
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

$ touch src1.tag

$ make -j8
touch .src1.tag
xmvlog src1.v
touch verilog.timestamp

$ touch hdr.vh

$ make -j8
touch .src3.tag
touch .src2.tag
touch .src1.tag
xmvlog src3.v src2.v src1.v
touch verilog.timestamp
```

Notes:

1. `$(TAGS): .%.tag: %.v hdr.vh` is a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern)
2. Of course, if you prefer separating the tag files from your source tree, you can store them in a dedicated sub-directory:

   ```
   SOURCES := $(wildcard *.v)
   TAGSDIR := .tags
   TAGS    := $(patsubst %.v,$(TAGSDIR)/.%.tag,$(SOURCES))

   all: $(TAGSDIR)/verilog.timestamp

   .PHONY: all

   $(TAGS): $(TAGSDIR)/.%.tag: %.v hdr.vh | $(TAGSDIR)
       touch $@

   $(TAGSDIR)/verilog.timestamp: $(TAGS) | $(TAGSDIR)
       xmvlog $(patsubst $(TAGSDIR)/.%.tag,%.v,$?)
       touch $@

   $(TAGSDIR):
       mkdir -p $@

   clean::
       rm -rf $(TAGSDIR)
   ```
3. In the last version `| $(TAGSDIR)` is an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is better, but... you could `touch` the sources when the header has been modified:

```
SOURCES := src1.v src2.v src3.v

verilog.timestamp: $(SOURCES) | hdr.vh
    xmvlog $?

$(SOURCES): hdr.vh
    @touch $@
```

(Note that [`$?` does not include](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types).)